# Trying to echo the string value instead of the $string

Tags: linux, string, shell, echo

I have a script that creates a string called loc and it holds "/home/database/", that is the directory in which it is located. This is a static value and changes from user to user.

```
    loc = $PWD
```

When I echo append this to my .bashrc, it appends $loc instead of /home/database/, which is a problem because loc isnt defined in the .bashrc

I am using this line of code:

```
    echo '$loc' >> ~/.bashrc
```

How would I append the hard, actual value of loc, instead of $loc?

Comment: Surely you intend to append something else than just a directory to `.bashrc`, despite what your command in the question seems to do? Also note, `loc = $PWD` is invalid bash command, it must be `loc=$PWD` without those extra spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes (i.e  `"$loc"`) rather than single quotes, as these will stop the variable from being expanded. See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/) for more info.